# Xcode accidentally deleted my files

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-sierra

I was looking through my project files and i saw that there is two .xcodeworkspace & .xcodeproject file (1.xcodeworkspace, 1.xcodeproject & 2.xcodeworkspace,2.xcodeproject).

I was always opening the first set of them but when I opened the second one to see what is the difference it deleted some of my xcode project files and emptied my storyboard file. Why this happened and is there any way to recover them?

I have already used Dr. Drill and recovered some of them but still there are some remained and they are for an important project.

Comment: Have you checked in the Trash? You should have used any source control system like **git**.

Comment: It is easy to think of it afterwards, but remember always take backup as you work on your projects... :(

Comment: Trash was empty and i didn't used git either...8 years of programming and never got into this kind of problem to need a backup. Xcode is really weird :( what about a question message before deleting files?

Comment: @MojtabaIranpanah open "1.xcodeworkspace". Is it showing something?

Comment: @AnuragSharma It's my project but the files are deleted (They are removed from finder and showing in Red on Xcode project navigator.). The most strange thing is Main.storyboard isn't deleted it just got emptied i have opened it in text editor too and it's just empty with one simple view controller.

Comment: @MojtabaIranpanah May be you can find more than one `storyBoard` in your project! Rough guess.

Comment: @AnuragSharma No there was no other Storyboard. it's really weird why this happened because i have disabled VCS too. I have search for storyboards inside that disk and opened each one of them no luck there either it seems i have to rewrite them. thanks for comment :)